# After upgrading Enthought Canopy to 1.4.1.1975 the Package Manager stopped operating

Tags: canopy

I have installed Enthought Canopy on Windows XP (32-bit) and on Windows 7 (64-bit).
After upgrading both installations to version 1.4.1.1975 I cannot operate 
Package Manager. It displays error message:

```
Could not connect to Canopy server.
Please check your network connection.
Package manager will not be able to update or install new packages.
If you are behind a proxy firewall, please check your proxy settings in the 
Preferences dialog
```

I had no problems with versions 1.3.0.1715 or 1.3.1.1876. I am not using proxy.
I am using AVG and have added exception for pythonw.exe so can still
run all my programs.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the trouble. Misleadingly (to be fixed in next release), this message also appears if your credentials were not accepted. Please try to log in on the Enthought web site, and if you can log in there ok, then log out of Canopy, quit, restart, and log back in. If your credentials do not succeed in either location, please email login.support@enthought.com

Answer (score 1):

Problem was successfully solved by Logout from Canopy and then Login back to Canopy.
These steps were also suggested by another subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I don't have an Enthought account. Uninstalling and downloading the latest version solved it.